# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor manually triggered

Tags: python, airflow

I have created two dags which I want to trigger manually `schedule_interval=None`.

First, I trigger "External_test_A" which should be pending till the "External_test_B" will not be triggered. After a while (after 2 minutes) I trigger "External_test_B" DAG, which runs only one task `first_task`.

When the task: `first_task` is success, then `Poking for External_test_B.first_task` from "External_test_A", should finished, return success and run `second_task` task from "External_test_A".

I stuck in the situation where even if `first_task` is a success, the `Poking for ...` from "External_test_A" is still going.

External_test_A:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': pendulum.yesterday().astimezone('US/Eastern')
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='External_test_A',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)

def do_second_task():
    print('Second task is done')

sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_the_first_task_to_be_completed',
    external_dag_id='External_test_B',
    external_task_id='first_task',
    execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=3),
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='second_task',
    python_callable=do_second_task,
    dag=dag)

sensor >> t2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

External_test_B:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': pendulum.yesterday().astimezone('US/Eastern')
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='External_test_B',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)

t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='first_task', dag=dag)

t1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

Does some of you could tell me what I'm doing wrong? How to solve the problem with communication between two tasks from two different DAGs using only manual trigger?

Comment: Looks like you can not trigger child dag manually, as per https://luminousmen.com/post/airflow-dag-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research there is no way to do this with manual trigger unless you write your own class to do the job. Both dags have to have a schedule interval with same start date and you need to mention execution_delta in external sensor definition.

Comment: The other post you mentioned was deleted for not being an answer. I edited this one to make it as much of an answer as possible. Please try to improve even more and make it as much as possible as recommended by [answer]. By the way, asking others to add a bounty is not really how that works. Please take the [tour].

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30079038)

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to your problem since both of your dags are manually triggered.
I suggest you try to do it in one DAG...

Comment: This suites more of a comment rather than an answer.You can find more information on how to write good answers ![in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30858433)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a third DAG, the triggerer, which will launch the two DAGs with the right execution dates (which is how Airflow knows the task of which DAG Run to listen to in the ExternalTaskSensor).

```
@dag(
dag_id="trigger_AB",
start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 9),
catchup=False,
schedule=None
)
def trigger():
    EXEC_DATE = '{{ ts }}'
    triggerA = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_A",
        trigger_dag_id="External_test_A",
        execution_date=EXEC_DATE
    )

    triggerB = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_B",
        trigger_dag_id="External_test_B",
        execution_date=EXEC_DATE
    )

my_dag = trigger()
```

Now if you trigger this DAG, it will launch both DAGs A and B and the DAG A will wait for the task in DAG B to finish before continuing, as expected.